# Android Child Coroutines Not Cancelling Appropriately (SupervisorJob)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I have a class that launches coroutines and allows them to be cancelled when the Activity/Fragment they are called from is destroyed. However it is not working like I expect. When I back out of the fragment while the operation is running, the coroutine cancel does not take, and I get an NPE when trying to access a `View` that does not exist anymore.

```
open class CoroutineLauncher : CoroutineScope {

    private val dispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.Main
    private val supervisorJob = SupervisorJob()
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = dispatcher + supervisorJob

    fun launch(action: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit) = launch(block = action)

    fun cancelCoroutines() {
        supervisorJob.cancelChildren() //coroutineContext.cancelChildren() has same results
    }
}
```

here is the usage

```
class MyFragment : Fragment {

  val launcher = CoroutineLauncher()

  fun onSomeEvent() {

    launcher.launch {

      val result = someSuspendFunction()

      if (!isActive) return

      // CAUSES CRASH
      myTextView.text = result.userText

    }

  }

  override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    launcher.cancelCoroutines()
  }

}
```

I added log lines to ensure `onDestroyView` and `cancelCoroutines` are both being called before the crash. I feel like I'm missing something obvious but what I'm doing seems to be inline with the recipes suggested here: https://proandroiddev.com/android-coroutine-recipes-33467a4302e9

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out. `onSomeEvent` was being invoked after `cancelCoroutines` was called. Since we call `cancelChildren` on the `SupervisorJob` instead of `cancel`, the launcher does not refuse new Jobs, and since the cancel already happened, the new coroutine runs like normal and crashes. I fixed this by checking if the fragment is visible before calling `launcher.launch` and bailing out of the method if the fragment is not visible.

This could also be fixed by calling `supervisorJob.cancel()` instead of `supervisorJob.cancelChildren()`, though that has some other side effects that I didn't want